# How do I run this code in Windows/on Powershell?

Tags: windows, bash, powershell, unix, wget

I'm trying to download a collection of files, but the instructions are for the command line in Unix.  Essentially, I have a .txt file that's a very long list of wget commands, each is pretty much

```
wget -U Mozilla/5.0 --no-check-certificate https://some-url.com
```

with a different url.  It says to execute the following in the command line

```
chmod a+x filename.txt

Execute: ./filename.txt
```

However, nothing has been working because I'm working in Windows.  Is there any way to download these files from this .txt file, or run the wget commands in Windows?  Thanks!

Comment: Did you consider doing  a Google search for *wget for Windows* before you posted here?

Comment: Are you attempting this in a bash-for-windows environment or in a WSL distribution? With either, you want the first line in your file to be `#!/bin/bash` to set the interpreter to be used for the remainder of the script. You can then make the script executable (e.g. `chmod +x filename.txt`) and then run it with `./filename.txt`. Alternatively, simply run it with bash, (e.g. `bash filename.txt`). (you will need `wget` installed within that environment)

Answer (score 1):

You can get wget for Windows [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm).

In Windows PowerShell, `wget` is an alias for `Invoke-WebRequest`, which won't take the same options as "real" wget. However, once you have a wget.exe for windows, you could do something like the following:

```bsh
Set-Alias wget wget.exe -Force -Option AllScope # point 'wget' at the real 'wget.exe'

copy ./filename.txt ./filename.ps1
. ./filename.ps1 # <-- "dot source" operator
```

But if each line in the file really is just a wget command line... you could also just use cmd just as well.

```bsh
copy ./filename.txt ./filename.cmd
cmd.exe /c ./filename.cmd
```